# Open files in a loop using Dir

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a file, copy from it then paste to another document, copy from that and paste back into the opened document.

I converted the file names to strings and it recognizes that but says they don't exist.

```
Dim StrFile As String

'Debug.Print "in LoopThroughFiles. inputDirectoryToScanForFile: ", inputDirectoryToScanForFile

StrFile = Dir("H:\Open Work book" & "\" & "*.xlsx")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    StrFile = Dir

    'Opens The File In The folder
    Workbooks.Open StrFile
```

This should open the files in a loop. It says

> Sorry, we couldn't find CTM Service Reach.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved renamed or deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
 StrFile = Dir("H:\Open Work book" & "\" & "*.xlsx")
```

strfile gets filled with the first file matching the pattern. You check that something is returned

```
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
```

but then you change strfile into the next file meeting the pattern - throwing away the first file's name

```
 StrFile = Dir
```

Then you attempt to open the file without specifying where it is

```
  Workbooks.Open StrFile
```

what you should be doing is

```
StrFile = Dir("H:\Open Work book" & "\" & "*.xlsx")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
   Workbooks.Open "H:\Open Work book" & "\" & StrFile
   StrFile = Dir
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, you have your solution but, hey, like the Romans used to say: variatio delectat. Here's another way of doing this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    strDir = "H:\Open Work book\"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDir)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile) = "xlsx" Then
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(objFile)
            // You code here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```